# Envio de correos mediante PHPMailer funciona en localhost pero no en el servidor real

Tags: php, phpmailer

He implementado el envío de correos mediante PHPMailer, y cuando envio los correos estando el proyecto en el localhost de mi servidor local no hay problema para mandarlos, pero ahora que tengo el proyecto en el servidor web el envio de correos ya no funciona, espero alguien pueda ayudarme a entender que he hecho mal o que es necesario cambiar una vez implementado el proyecto.

Este es el codigo que estoy usando para el envio de los correos:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

// $body = '
//     <h3> Estimado c. '. $nombre .' su reserva en '. $establecimiento .' para el dia ' . $fecha. ' a las ' . $hora . ' </h3>
//     <h1> HA SIDO CONFIRMADA EXITOSAMENTE </h1>
// ';


    if(isset($_POST['valor'])) {

        $valor = $_POST['valor'];

    }

    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($valor); echo '</pre>';

    $tiempo = time();
    $codigo = $valor + $tiempo;

    //echo $codigo;


    $reservas = ControladorReservas::ctrMostrarReservas($valor);
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($reservas); echo '</pre>';

    foreach ($reservas as $reserva) {
        $id = $reserva['id'];
        $correo = $reserva['correo'];
        $nombre = $reserva['nombre_reserva'];
        $establecimiento = $reserva['establecimiento'];
        $fecha = $reserva['fecha_reserva'];
        $hora = $reserva['hora_reserva'];
    }

    #echo $correo . ' ' . $nombre . ' ' . $codigo;

    //$correo = 'ekamstarr@gmail.com';  //ESTE ESTA HARDCODED, PARA USAR EL VALIDO DESCOMENTAR EL DEL FOREACH Y COMENTAR ESTE
    $titulo = 'Su reserva en / Your booking at '. $establecimiento .' ha sido confirmada / has been confirmed';
    $cuerpo = '

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Demystifying Email Design</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        </head>
        <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 10px 0 30px 0;">
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc; border-collapse: collapse;">
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px;">
                                                <b>Estimado / Dear ' . $nombre . ',</b>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding: 20px 0 30px 0; color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">
                                                <p> Su reservacion para '. $establecimiento .' el dia '. $fecha .' a las '. $hora .' horas HA SIDO CONFIRMADA EXITOSAMENTE </p>
                                                <p> Your booking for '. $establecimiento .' the day '. $fecha .' at '. $hora .' hours HAS BEEN CONFIRMED SUCCESSFULLY </p>

                                                <h3> Su codigo de reserva es / Your booking code is: ' . $codigo . '</h3>
                                                <p> Recuerde proporcionar su codigo de reserva para hacer valido su regalo </p>
                                                <p> Remeber to proporcionate your booking code to make your gift valid </p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#4ECDC4" style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;" width="75%">
                                                &reg; Rede, 2019<br/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>

    ';

    require_once('PHPMailer/PhpMailerAutoload.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = '465';
    $mail->isHTML();
    $mail->Username = 'correo@correo.com';
    $mail->Password = "pass01";
    $mail->SetFrom('prueba@quis.org');

    //Estas 3 siguientes son personalizadas

    $mail->Subject = $titulo;                           //Titulo del correo
    $mail->Body = $cuerpo;                                //Body del correo
    $mail->AddAddress($correo);                         //Correo al que se manda

    $mail->Send();

?>



<body>
  <!-- ****************************************************
      MAIN CONTENT
      ***************************************************** -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 p404 centered mt">
        <h1>LA RESERVA HA SIDO COMPLETADA.</h1>
        <h3>El código de la reservación le ha sido enviado al cliente.</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Gracias por confirmar la reserva, recuerde tener todo listo<br>¡Mucho exito!</h3>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <a href="<?php echo $ruta . 'panel-reservas'; ?>"><button class="btn btn-theme mt">Aceptar</button></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <h4 class="mt">No olvide solicitar el código al arribo del cliente.</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Los datos del correo emisor y su contraseña los he cambiado por obvias razones en esta publicacion, pero esos datos no son el problema.

Como mayor informacion, el proyecto esta implementado en un servidor LAMP de AWS, en el cual les menciono que el envio de correos no funciona.

Espero puedan ayudarme, y quedo al pendiente por cualquier comentario.

¡De antemano, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Revisa los SecurityGroups de tu instancia, puede ser que tenga bloqueado el puerto 465 de salida y por eso no se envie el correo.

puedes encontrar los security groups en:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-1#SecurityGroups:sort=groupId

recuerda ingresar en la region donde tienes el server configurado.